# Arrow key control of wheelnav.js

Tags: javascript, wheelnav.js

I am using the really nice [wheelnav.js](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/) library to visually select some items out of a large number of items. I have around 50 items in the wheel which is why I am only showing the part of the wheel where the selected item is currently located. I would like to be able to scroll through the wheel using left-right arrow keys. I have made a fiddle to somewhat demonstrate what I would like to do:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmfj0aoL/7/)

I am detecting keydown events like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
e = e || window.e;
var keyCodeEvent = e.which || e.keyCode; 

if([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
    }
if (keyCodeEvent === 37 || keyCodeEvent === 40) {
    forward(1, "forward");
    }
if (keyCodeEvent === 38 || keyCodeEvent === 39) {
    backward(-1, "backward");
    }
}, false);
```

I put the forward and backward functions in the wheelnav.js library and I am trying to rotate the wheel as such

```
this.forward = function (a,b) {    
   wheelnav.prototype.navigateWheel(a);
}
```

The mouse click to rotate works fine but when I use the arrows I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCurrentTransform' of undefined.

Is anyone using this library and do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable keyboard via [keynavigateEnabled](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/documentation/core.html#sectionKeynav) property (left-right arrow keys are the default).

```
wheel.keynavigateEnabled = true;
```

PS: It is available from v1.7.0, here is your modified [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmfj0aoL/9/)